How to configure postfix to pipe all incoming email to a script using Plesk?
Basically, I'd like the same functionality as in this question. I only run into the issue that whenever I add
transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport, hash:/etc/postfix/transport

to the main.cf file, indeed the script gets executed, but the email will no longer be stored in the inbox. I'd like to keep it as a backup. How can I achieve this?
